# Reorder columns based on column suffixes

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
all_data = pd.merge(all_data, meanData, suffixes=["", "_mean"], how='left', on=['id', 'id2'])
```

Now, I want to merge `all_data` and `meanData`, but I want the columns of meanData to appear first.

Like this:

> a_mean,b_mean,c_mean,a,b,c

Not like this

> a,b,c,a_mean,b_mean,c_mean

Note: I have a lot of columns, So i do not want to manually write code to change index.

Sample Code (you can reproduce):

```
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1, 2], [0,1, 3], [0,4, 6],[1,3,4],[1,4,2]], columns=['id','A', 'B'])
features = ['A','B']
meanData = df.groupby(['id'])[features].agg('mean')
df = pd.merge(df, meanData, suffixes=["", "_mean"], how='left', on=['id'])
print(df.columns)
```

Output

> Index(['id', 'A', 'B', 'A_mean', 'B_mean'], dtype='object')

Expected output:

> Index(['A_mean', 'B_mean','id', 'A', 'B'], dtype='object')

Comment: Sorry, I mean `pd.merge(meanData, all_data, suffixes=["_mean", ""], how='right', on=['id', 'id2'])`

Comment: Same result @coldspeed :/

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] with some data as text and expected output edited into your question? I will reopen your post once it is clear what you have tried and what has not worked.

Comment: Done @coldspeed

Comment: @JohnDoe do you use the dataframe `meanData` for something else or it is just to add the columns '_mean' in your original dataframe `df`?

Comment: I use it for also calculating `meanRank`, after that I delete `meanData`, to save memory.

Comment: @JohnDoe my answer does not include the `meanData` as I'm not sure what you mean by `meanRank`

Comment: Just `.reindex` to ensure the same column order: `df.reindex(['A_mean', 'B_mean', 'id', 'A', 'B'], axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) after the `groupby` to get the `mean` related to each row, and then `pd.concat` the dataframes such as:

```
new_df = pd.concat([(df.groupby('id')[features]
                       .transform(np.mean).add_suffix('_mean')), df],
                   axis=1)
print (new_df)
   A_mean    B_mean  id  A  B
0     2.0  3.666667   0  1  2
1     2.0  3.666667   0  1  3
2     2.0  3.666667   0  4  6
3     3.5  3.000000   1  3  4
4     3.5  3.000000   1  4  2
```

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning this earlier, but I use `mean` for `meanRank` also,
`    meanDataRank = mean.groupby('id')[features].rank(pct=True).reset_index()`

Comment: @JohnDoe I assume `mean` is what you called `meanData` from your question. If so, I don't see the point of using `groupby` as meanData has only one row per id, no? or do you want to rank the values within each group of id?

Comment: Ids are not unique. Yeah, i want to calculate meanRank using mean dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge and reorder columns with `sorted()`:

```
v = pd.merge(df, meanData, suffixes=["", "_mean"], how='left', on=['id'])
v[sorted(v.columns, key=lambda x: 'mean' not in x)]

   A_mean    B_mean  id  A  B
0     2.0  3.666667   0  1  2
1     2.0  3.666667   0  1  3
2     2.0  3.666667   0  4  6
3     3.5  3.000000   1  3  4
4     3.5  3.000000   1  4  2
```